# jQuery validate if input not empty

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-validate

Good day. Help set Validate plugin to update user profile.
There are two input fields, `"new password"` and `"repeat new password"`.

Need if they are both empty, it does not perform any checks. And if in the "Password" something entered, the password check for validity and equality of the second password.
I tried something like this, but this "if" does not work.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(select)" });

        $('#contact-form').validate({

        rules: {         
         if(passord.lenght){
            password: {
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 25,
            required: true,
            loginRegex: true
          },
          password_repeat: {
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 25,
           required: true,
            loginRegex: true,
            equalTo: "#password"
          }}
        },
});
```

I was looking for the answer in similar topics, but not found.

Comment: I'm guessing this has been coded quite a number of times. Take a look at sites like this one: http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/milk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
<form id="formCheckPassword">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password"/>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="cfmPassword" id="cfmPassword" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
 </form>



 $("#formCheckPassword").validate({
           rules: {
               password: { 
                 required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    maxlength: 10,

               } , 

                   cfmPassword: { 
                    equalTo: "#password",
                     minlength: 6,
                     maxlength: 10
               }


           },
     messages:{
         password: { 
                 required:"the password is required"

               }
     }

});
```

Comment: Everything was easier than I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I like the first answer, but personally would not include the

```
minlength: 6,
maxlength: 10
```

In the cfmPassword.  Either the first password matches the criteria, or generates an error.  If that doesn't generate an error, the second password just has to match it.